# UVWarp modifier scales the UV image

Tags: uv, bones, image

When I'm dragging the bones across this image, it seems to change each 'mouth' every pixel I move the bone. It's suppose to move to each 'mouth' the same distance as it is to each mouth on the image. What's the fix so I can move it more easily?

How it's supposed to work (tutorial): [Blender 2.7 Tutorial #62 : Face Texture Animation Rig #b3d](https://youtu.be/5NlvgMYZgaY?t=24m50s)

[image]