# Using UVWarp modifier to position part of an image on an object

Tags: uv, modifiers, snapping

I have been attempting to use the uvwarp modifier to position parts of an image on an object. More specifically, the image is a subdivided plane composed of a number of mouths (to choose from) with which I would like to be able to use a bone to move from one mouth to another. The chosen mouth will then be displayed on another plane (a display plane - which has a uvwarp modifier and has been edited in the uv editor to display one mouth at a time). However, when moving the bone along the image's subdivided grid, intending to choose a mouth, the snapping alignment and the mouth display do not stay consistent. For instance, if I move the bone an arbitrary snapping unit and then move it back to its original position, at a later point in time (whether in pose or object mode), the mouth that was originally position with the bone's original position has changed. Furthermore, if I move the bone anywhere else along the image's grid, the mouths, which should match the position of the bone, do not stay aligned to where the bone is positioned.

The file works fine when snapping is turned off. However, when snapping is turned on, these issues arise. Therefore, I have been trying to figure out why this is occurring because I need to have snapping enabled in order to position the mouth accurately for various keyframes.

[image: Using UVWarp modifier on objects picture 1[[1][image: Using UVWarp modifier on objects picture 2[[2][image: Using UVWarp modifier on objects picture 3[[3][image: Using UVWarp modifier on objects picture 4[[4]
This question appears to be similar to another question posted, but was not answered.
[UVWarp modifier scales the UV image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77289/uvwarp-modifier-scales-the-uv-image)

Does anyone have any suggestions as how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I am using the same system as you for the mouths on several short animations. I quit using snaps. When I want a different mouth i use poses and pose libraries

Answer (score 2):

Found out how to do it through this forum. https://blenderartists.org/t/uvwarp-not-mapping-correctly-with-lego-mouth-annimation/1118084/3 When imported the image into the file, I scaled it up and then set the scale back to 1. This caused the issue. However, when trying to fix it, I imported the image again and did not adjust the scale. Now it's working.

Comment: I would have cropped the image, in an external editor, to the desired part (selection 1:1), loaded it and scaled with nodes.